# Telebot не переходит от одной функции к другой

Tags: python, telebot, photo

Всем привет, пишу бота обрабатывающего картинки присылая текст с них и столкнулся с проблемой из функции handler_file не переходит к get_languagе, что делать?

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, parse_mode='html')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
name = None

photo_list = []


def PhotoSave(imag, message, language='rus'):
    img = Image.open(imag)
    file_name = img.filename
    file_name = file_name.split(".")[0]
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang=language).strip()
    bot.reply_to(message, text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Присылай фото')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, handler_file)
    return


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document'])
def handler_file(message):
    from pathlib import Path
    Path(f'files/{message.chat.id}/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = f'files/{message.chat.id}/' + file_info.file_path.replace('photos/', '')
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Фото вос бин сохранен!')

    elif message.content_type == 'document':
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = f'files/{message.chat.id}/' + message.document.file_name
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Файл вос бин сохранен!')

    else:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'пришлите фото')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, get_language)
    return


def get_language(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Загружаю...')
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, msg.message_id)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Русский", callback_data='rus')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Английский", callback_data='en')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите язык', reply_markup=markup)
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    return


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    language = None
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'rus':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'РУССКИЙ')
            elif call.data == 'en':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'АНГЛИЙСКИЙ')

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                  text="Выберите язык",
                                  reply_markup=None)

            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                                      text=f"Вы выбрали{call.data}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bot.register_next_step_handler(send, get_language)

Бот после перехода будет ожидать ввода от пользователя.
Если ввод не нужен просто инициируйте запуск функции
get_language(send)

Comment: спасибо, к слову не знаешь как передать message в callback?

Comment: markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Текст кнопки", callback_data=f"callback")

Рекомендую параллельно знакомиться с FSMContext для хранения данных